# Convert JSON to XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, json

Are there any .jars out there that can be used to convert JSON to XML? A lot of the answers on SO contain dead links or involve complex configuration.

Ideally it would be nice just to include a jar in my existing project that currently converts XML to JSON. I just need it the other way around to be complete.

Comment: Have a look at [apache camel](http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html)

Comment: Did you check http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml(json)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article:

- http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/279-how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-java/

From the article:

> Use json-lib, a library which adds JSON support to any Java program. json-lib provides an XMLSerializer which can be used to output XML from a JSON object.

Comment: Indeed this is faster, but the output xml is a bit crappy.

Comment: There are always tradeoffs

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to convert JSON to java classes (using GSON for instance), then the java classes to XML (possibly using JAXB). Then you'll have a comprehensive way to manage how you want to perform the conversion.